# Can the iPad Pro be used as input to a Linux computer?

Tags: linux, ipad, drawing, collaboration

I have a Linux desktop that I often use for online conferencing.  In conferences I need to field questions, often aided by drawing diagrams.  Up to now I've been doing this with a Wacom writing pad, but being unable to write directly on the screen makes drawings ugly.  I recently ordered an iPad Pro to real-time share diagrams, interfaced through some kind of web application to make and share them (BitPaper, Ziteboard, ScribbleTogether, Scribblar).

However, it occurs to me that perhaps it could be even better if the iPad could show the computer's display and I could write onto the iPad to control the mouse on the computer.  I think I'd still be relying on a web application to make and real-time share the drawings.  But it might be easier to sync files if I need to copy-paste text or pictures stored on the desktop into the shared drawing.

So is it possible to use the iPad as a pen input to a Linux computer (where the iPad is also showing the computer's display)? Or are there iPad apps that would facilitate this kind of conferencing in some other way?

Comment: The only way you could really do this is to remote in from your iPad to the target computer. Remote desktop software can do that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Operating_system_support provides a list of remote desktop apps which you can sort to find Linux server apps, and resort for MacOS X clients.

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible on Linux and macOS systems with a project I have created called [Weylus](https://github.com/H-M-H/Weylus). Screen mirroring, pressure sensitivity, tilt and multi touch are supported.

Weylus turns your tablet or smart phone into a graphic tablet/touch screen for your computer!

Comment: Very cool! Self-promotion is fine as long as you are clear about it. Interesting stuff!